# Getting to BIOS on the Lenovo IdeaPad U530 Touch in order to install Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, uefi

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad U530 Touch with Windows 8 preinstalled. I tried to install Elementary OS, but discovered that the WiFi support wasn't there, so I decided to switch to Arch Linux.

The problem is that I can't seem to access UEFI/BIOS (I'm not sure which I'm supposed to do. I'm a newbie to this, but I think I need to go to UEFI), no matter which keys I press on startup (when the Lenovo logo appears). I have a USB drive with Arch Linux installed by using the Universal USB Installer software which I want to use to install Arch once I get to the UEFI/BIOS and configure it to boot from the USB first.

I can no longer access Windows because of the Elementary OS installation. Any ideas?

Comment: Unable to leave an answer at this time, so I'm leaving a comment for now: Press Fn + F6 once you hit the "lenovo" logo screen upon booting up, it should take you to a boot menu.

Comment: Did you ever get Arch Linux installed? Did you every get bumblebee configured?

Answer (score 3):

using FN+F2 I could get in to my BIOS

to be able to boot up from a USB driver, in Boot menu I set both to "Legacy Mode Support"

then I re-start, and entered the Bios again, to see the USB , and mSATA drive in the boot list order to put them in order that I wanted.

having said that, I end up to put it back in the original setting to be able to boot from the original HDD.

I am still trying to boot from a USB, and move the OS partition to the mSATA drive to make my system faster. (Acronise was not helpful :(( )

Answer (score 3):

There is a small black button (maybe 1/8") on the left side of the laptop, right next to the ethernet port.  Shut down your laptop, then press this button.  It will start the computer up in Lenovo's recovery mode, which allows you to open your BIOS.